# Problem with XNA for Windows phone 7 development

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I can compile succesfully my game but when emulator is show than i get that error:
The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications

my nootebook have a graphics card that can handle DirectX 10.0. this is website with specification http://www.nvidia.pl/object/geforce_9600m_gt_pl.html
I installed DirectX 10.0 .XNA 4.0 from this site : http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started

-Harry 180

my operating system is windows 7 (x64)

yes i tried to update my DirectX and drivers

Comment: Have you tried updating your drivers and DirectX already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run Windows Vista, install [this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971512).

As a radical solution, you might need updating to Windows 7 (only if you are using Vista).

Comment: Did you try setting it to Reach profile instead of HiDef to see if it makes any difference ?